# When trying to stop RDS using ansible, I get an error saying i haven't provided enough parameters ApplyImmediately, AlocatedStorage, Iops

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, ansible, boto3, amazon-rds

Below is a snippet from my Ansible playbook

```
  tasks:
    - name: Stop RDSs
      rds_instance:
        region: us-west-2
        aws_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        aws_secret_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        id: "my_instance_id"
        skip_final_snapshot: true
        state: stopped
```

The error I am getting is

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: Invalid type for parameter Iops, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'int'>
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"boto3_version": "1.26.101", "botocore_version": "1.29.101", "changed": false, "msg": "Unexpected failure for method modify_db_instance with parameters {'AllocatedStorage': None, 'Iops': None, 'DBInstanceIdentifier': 'my_instance_id', 'ApplyImmediately': False}: Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter AllocatedStorage, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'int'>\nInvalid type for parameter Iops, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'int'>"}
```

and when i explicitly add all the parameters the error statement lists,

```
allocated_storage: 150  
iops: 1000
apply_immediately: true
```

the playbook finishes without any errors but the rds doesn't get stopped.

Also this is only happening to a specific set of RDSs, the playbook above works fine with other RDSs in my stack.

My ansible version details are as follows

```
ansible [core 2.14.4]
 python version = 3.10.10 [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] (/usr/local/bin/python)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried running the playbook in higher verbose? you can also troubleshoot further to see if the API call is making there and handle that specific set of RDS. Here is a link for troubleshooting further https://www.ansible.com/blog/troubleshoot-rds-connectivity-issues-with-ansible-validated-content

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).